# Установка пакета MySQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.x, pycharm

Хочу установить пакет MySQL, чтобы использовать его в django. Однако после ввода команды `pip install mysql-python` появляется ошибка:

```
(diploma_project) E:\diploma_project>pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command e:\diploma_project\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx2zlahz\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ivedejm1\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers e:\diploma_project\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient:
    C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "e:\diploma_project\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx2zlahz\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ivedejm1\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers e:\diploma_project\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nx2zlahz\mysqlclient\
```

Для установки пакета mysql одной команды достаточно или нужно ещё что-то? После успешной установки надо ли что-либо изменять в файле settings.py или в других файлах? Просто я с этим сталкиваюсь впервые.

Comment: Зачем вы указываете метку python2, если у вас python3? На разных версиях могут быть свои ошибки. Не нужно дизинформировать людей :) Судя по ошибке, для установки нужно будет скомпилировать модуль, поэтому установщик пошел искать Visual Studio. Тут я вижу такие варианты: 1) найти .whl (wheel) под mysqlclient 2) установить требуемое и повторить 3) установить вместо python -- anaconda и через нее установить mysqlclient. У анаконды есть куча собранных модулей, позволяет через pip устанавливать, и добавляет свой pip -- conda: `conda install mysqlclient`

Comment: Насчет 2), посмотрите в https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: У вас только эта команда не работает, или вообще pip приказал долго жить?

Comment: @gil9red Скачал mysqlclient  попытался установить с помощью команды `pip install E:\mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`, но появляется ошибка `mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`. Если я правильно понял, то это означает что данный пакет не поддерживается. Однако я скачивал разные версии, всё равно та же ошибка повторяется. Скачивал отсюда https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient.

Comment: @FedotSoldier только эта команда не работает

Comment: Ну тут уже видимо действительно у них что-то не так

Comment: @gil9redr я установил mysql-connector и mysqlclient с помощью Conda Navigator.Что надо сделать, что надо сделать, чтобы я мог применять эти пакеты в pycharm?

Comment: @НеуловимыйДжо, ну... видите в названии `cp27-cp27m`? Это указывает версию питона. Вам, думаю, подошла бы версия `mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` А насчет пичарма с анакондой... в пичарме откройте Файл/Настройки там будет пункт с вашим проектом в нем будет пункт Проектный интерпретатор. Тыкните на него и выберите в выпадающем списке питон в папке анаконды. Например `Python 3.6.1 (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe)`