# Импорт данных из MySQL в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.x, python-3.5

Как подключиться к серверу MySQL и импортировать эти данные в Django? На данный момент я установил mysql-installer-community-8.0.13.0, пакет mysqlclient для django, а также в **settings.py** добавил кое какие изменения:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sakilla',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Host и Port взял из MySQL. Пробовал следовать указаниям приведённые в данной статье https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/ Однако при выполнении команды `python manage.py inspectdb` появляется ошибка:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 31, in handle
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 47, in handle_inspection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\diploma_project\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)
```

Comment: Ошибка 2059 говорит о каких-то проблемах с аутентификацией на MySQL-сервере. Это может быть вызвано какими-нибудь несовместимостями. Какая у вас версия Django? Какая у вас версия MySQLdb? Как устанавливали?

Comment: @andreymal Версия Django: 2.1.3; версия Mysqlclient: 1.3.13

Comment: @andreymal выполнил в Mysql следующий запрос                                                    `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';` потом повторил команду `python manage.py inspectdb` в терминале появилось следующее: `class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    manager_staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, models.DO_NOTHING, unique=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'store'`

Comment: Вот и хорошо, можно следовать дальше алгоритму по вашей ссылке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем так как у меня возникло куча проблем при выполнение миграции БД из MySQL в Django, решил описать весь алгоритм от начало до конца, вдруг кому-нибудь пригодиться.
Я использовал следующие программы и программные пакеты:

**JetBrains PyCharm 2018.2.4**

**Python 3.7**

**mysqlclient-1.3.13** (скачивал отсюда:https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

**mysql-installer-community-8.0.13.0**

**Django: 2.1.3**

1)Устанавливаем: JetBrains PyCharm 2018.2.4, mysql-installer-community-8.0.13.0, Python 3.7

2)Создаем новый проект Django в JetBrains PyCharm 2018.2.4

3)Далее следует установить mysqlclient-1.3.13. Для этого в терминале PyCharm (Views->Tools Windows->Terminal) переходим в папку Scripts введя команду `cd Scripts`. Потом активируем нашу виртуальную среду с помощью команды `activate`. Копируем наш mysqlclient в удобное для нас место, в данном случае это **диск Е**. В терминале с помощью команды `cd ..` переходим в наш **диск E**. И выполняем команду `pip install E:\mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`

4)После переходим в PyCharm находим файл settings.py и меняем **параметр DATABASES**:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Имя БД',
        'USER': 'Имя пользователя',
        'PASSWORD': 'пароль',
        'HOST': 'имя хоста',
        'PORT': 'порт',
    }
}
```

Все данные берём из MySQL. Если кто-то не знает как их получать, для начала следует запустить MySQL Workbench. Далее, где появляется надпись MySQL Connections, следует нажать на гаечный ключ. После у вас появятся необходимые данные.

5) Далее в MySQL выполняем следующий запрос:

```
ALTER USER 'имя пользователя'@'имя хоста'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'пароль';
```

6) С помощью команды `cd` в терминале переходим в директорию где находится файл manage.py и выполняем следующую команды:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
python manage.py inspectdb> models.py
python manage.py migrate
```

ссылки которые вам возможно пригодятся:

[Установка пакета MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906803/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-mysql)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/

На этом всё.

P.S. Огромное спасибо всем кто помог мне пройти через всё это!Ну и отдельная благодарность создателям данного форума:)